# OAuth2, Facebook (multiple environments, localhost, azure)

Tags: facebook, azure

I have the basic OAuth2 working with Facebook but it appears that I need to setup multiple apps in FaceBook to support. When I add platform, I can add only 1 web site and it has a URL.  Seems like I need multiple facebook apps to support different environment.

I can configure it for local host and it works, I can reconfigure it for azure and it works, but I can never get both to work. I did configure multiple re-direct URIs to each environment.

Am I correct that I will need multiple facebook apps (appid and app secret), one for each environment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need multiple apps for this to work under different domains. Facebook now offers the ability to create an app which is the "test version" of an existing app. You will still end up with different apps/app Ids so you need a way within your application to initialise the FB API with the app ID which is configured for the given environment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with "test version"?